# SharePoint 2013 search REST API

Tags: url, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I am trying to search items in SharePoint site by using this URL in the browser: `sites/esc/_api/search/query?querytext='Amit'`. But I am not able to retrieve the same number of results which are retrieved when the same item is searched in SharePoint site. The search with the URL retrieves only a few results as compared to the search in SharePoint site whereas the blogs on different websites states that the URL will give complete results. Can anyone please explain this or provide the URL to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the mistake. The URL which I was using was correct. The only thing was that by default it was taking the row limit to 20. On increasing the row limit I was able to get complete results.